# Google systems have recently detected that SharedArrayBuffers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain, postmessage, sharedarraybuffer

I recently received this message below from Google.  It says I am using SharedArrayBuffers but I have no idea what those are.  Is there a way to determine if I am using what they say I am?  The only type of cross domain stuff I am doing is within an iframe where I am calling script through postmessage on a different parent domain. However, I don't know if this is related to that.

```
Google systems have recently detected that SharedArrayBuffers (SABs) are used on https://basketball.exposureevents.com/, but COOP and/or COEP headers are not served.

For Web Compatibility reasons Chrome is planning to require COOP/COEP for the use of SABs from Chrome 91 (2021-05-25) onwards. Please implement 'cross-origin-isolated' behavior on your site.
```

Comment: I had the same email and asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642859/new-requirements-for-sharedarraybuffers-on-https-example-com. I'm pretty confused to be honest. If I get an answer on my question I'll update here.

Comment: Hi Mike - this page (https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/) was updated yesterday to provide advice re. how to find the page on your site that's using / or linking to Javascript that contains `SharedArrayBuffer` code. ON my site it turned out it was linked to some JS delivered via an advert.